# Knockout event binding for input keypress causes weird behavior

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, dom-events, keypress, html-input

Long story short, I want to enable users to hit enter on an input element and certain method in my viewmodel be called. Here is my html input:

```
<input id="searchBox" class="input-xxlarge" type="text" data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: $parent.searchKeyboardCmd}">
```

and here is my method in vm:

```
searchKeyboardCmd = function (data, event) { if (event.keyCode == 13) searchCmd(); };
```

everything works fine and `searchCmd` is called when I hit enter on input, but the problem is that I can type nothing in input, i.e. everything I type into input is ignored. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to KO docs you have to return `true` from your event handler if you want the default action proceed.

```
searchKeyboardCmd = function (data, event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) searchCmd();
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much f_martinez! It now works perfectly, though I don't see why was this necessary!

Answer (score 2):

[here's](http://jsfiddle.net/zWWzX/1/) a fiddle which demonstrates what ur trying to do and also replace event 'keypress' in ur code with keyup and remove $parent with only the function name unless the textfield is inside a knockout foreach loop..here is the below modified code

```
<input id="searchBox" class="input-xxlarge" type="text" data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keyup: searchKeyboardCmd}"
```

Comment: This was the answer that helped me, because it doesn't deppend on the enter or keycode==13

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/qG6yv/

```
<!-- ko with: stuff -->
  <input id="searchBox" class="input-xxlarge" type="text" 
    data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', 
    event: { keypress: $parent.searchKeyboardCmd}">   
<!-- /ko -->
```

And the javascript:

```
var stuffvm = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.searchText = ko.observable();
};

var vm = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.stuff = new stuffvm();

    self.searchCmd = function() {
        console.log("search triggered");
    };

    self.searchKeyboardCmd = function (data, event) { 
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            self.searchCmd(); 
        }
        return true;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```