# data-bind with keyup event does not trigger

Tags: html, data-binding, knockout.js, single-page-application

I have a text input element that I want user to enter city or zip code and I want to trigger a javascript function as the user types text. My html is as follows

```
       <input type="text"
        placeholder="Zip Code Or City Name"
        class="input-block-level"
        data-bind="value: searchterm, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keyup: getZipCodes }" />
```

in my viewmodel I have

```
var getZipCodes = function () {
        if (searchterm().length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        datacontext.getZips(searchterm(), zipcodes);
        return true;
    };
```

But it turns out that the getZipCodes is never invoked.

I tried data-binding to "onkeyup" but no go, I am sure there is some subtle error I am making. Can someone help me find what I am doing wrong?

I tried changing getZipCodes to getZipCodes = function(data, event) {...} but that does not work either. The function just does not get invoked.

By the way I am trying to do pretty much same as [Knockout event binding for input keypress causes weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120356/knockout-event-binding-for-input-keypress-causes-weird-behavior)

but does not work for me.

Comment: do you mean something like 
   data-bind="value: searchterm, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup', event: { keyup: getZipCodes }" />

or you are referring to the event name

The valueUpdate happens for me justfine, 

just that the getZipCodes function is never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the definition of getZipCodes as follows it started working.

```
function getZipCodes(data, event) {
        if (searchterm().length < 2) {
            return true;
        }

        datacontext.getZips(searchterm(), zipcodes);
        return true;
    };
```

Instead of

```
var getZipCodes = function()
```

if I use

```
function getZipCodes()....
```

it works, not really sure what the difference is.